# Prove that if a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ converges then $\{\sqrt a_{n}\}$ converges to the square root of the limit.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

My attempt and the question:Can you tell if I am right :)? thank you[image]

Comment: I do not understand your comment @MhenniBenghorbal :) can you explain more about it please :)

Comment: The inequality $\left|\frac{a_n-a}{\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a}}\right|<|a_n-a|$ is not true in general. But your idea is basically correct...

Comment: There are problems. Under the line with "we consider" you cannot have the inequality when $\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a} < 1$. A similar problem is at the very last line, what if all $a_n <1$? For example take $a_n = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: How can I fix it can you help me please :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1) $a = 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$, then there exists a $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $|a_n - 0| < \epsilon^2$. Thus: $|\sqrt{a_n} - 0| < \epsilon$. This shows that $\sqrt{a_n} \rightarrow 0$.

2) $a > 0$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $|a_n - a| < \epsilon\sqrt{a}$. Thus: $|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a}| = \dfrac{|a_n - a|}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a}} < \dfrac{|a_n - a|}{\sqrt{a}} < \dfrac{\epsilon\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}} = \epsilon$. This shows that $\sqrt{a_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: Thank @Dark-Chocolate, then with this the prove is done and you fix the problem :)

Comment: Yes because you fixed my problem and helped me to do a good  proof :)

Comment: but if the square root of "a" is a fraction then your second proof doesn't work

Comment: @RandomUser why not?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick answer when $a\neq 0$. Write

\begin{equation}
\lim (a_n^{1/2} - a^{1/2})\lim(a_n^{1/2} + a^{1/2}) = \lim(a_n-a)=0.
\end{equation}

Thus, $\lim(a_n^{1/2} + a^{1/2}) \neq 0$ and

\begin{equation}
\lim (a_n^{1/2} - a^{1/2}) = 0 \rightarrow\lim a_n^{1/2}=a^{1/2}.
\end{equation}