# Prove whether the following statement is true

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> If {$a_{n}^2$} is a convergent and $a_{n}>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then {$a_{n}$} is convergent

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem? What worked, what did not?

Comment: Please show your work and note that $a_n>0$ is important because for instance you can take $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: I think the statement is true - I tried to come with counter examples, however if $a_{n} > 0$ and convergent, so is $a_{n}^2$. However, I'm not sure how to prove it for a general case. @VictorBarg

Comment: Almost same:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923036/prove-that-if-a-sequence-a-n-converges-then-sqrt-a-n-converges

Comment: @VictorBarg thank you!